# Debugger indicates its not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-dialog

I have two javascript functions.  One I don't pass a value in and another that I do.  When viewing in the Chrome debugger, I get an error message that the function is not a valid function.

**GOOD ONE**

```
function CreateEmployee() {
    var div = $("#OpenDilog");
    div.load("/Home/Create", function () {
        div.dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            title: "Add New Employee",
            resizable: false
        });
    });
}
```

BAD ONE

```
function EditEmployee(E_ID) {
    alert("value: " + E_ID);
    var ph = $("#OpenDilog");
    ph.load("/Home/Edit?taskId=" + E_ID, function () {
        ph.dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            resizable: false
        });
    });
}
```

The alert box does pop up with the correct ID, but then it fails afterwords on ph.dialog is not a function.

The Controller signature is

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Edit(int taskId)
```

ENTIRE FILE

```
@model List<SFTPWatcherManager.Models.fals_ftp_watcher_manager_sp_Result>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    <style type="text/css">
        .grid {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
}

<div style="padding:7px 0;">
    <input type="button" value="Add New SFTP Watcher" onclick="CreateEmployee()" />

</div>

<div id='OpenDilog'></div>

<h3>Employee Information List</h3>

<div style="width:100%;">
    @{
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
        @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "grid",
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            firstText: "<< First",
            previousText: "< Prev",
            nextText: "Next >",
            lastText: "Last >>",
            columns: new[] {
                grid.Column("task_id",header: "ID"),
                grid.Column("task_name",header: "Name"),
                grid.Column("client"),
                grid.Column(format: @<text><input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="@item.task_id" /> </text>),
                grid.Column("Action", format: @<text><a href="#" , onclick="EditEmployee('@item.task_id');return false;">view</a></text>)
            }
        )
    }

</div>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")


<script type="text/javascript">

    function CreateEmployee() {
        var div = $("#OpenDilog");
        div.load("/Home/Create", function () {
            div.dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                title: "Add New Employee",
                resizable: false
            });
        });
    }

    function EditEmployee(E_ID) {
        alert("value: " + E_ID);
        var ph = $("#OpenDilog");
        ph.load("/Home/Edit?taskId=" + E_ID, function () {
            ph.dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                resizable: false
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe add the `jquery` tag?

Comment: Is a function that's actually available?

Comment: Can you show us the html? ph is empty

Comment: Does `/Home/Edit` return a `<script>` tag that loads another copy of jQuery? That would cause problems like this.

Comment: @Barmar the cshmtl file for edit has it included but so does the create.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not causing a problem with `Create`, but it seems wrong in both cases. You already have jQuery loaded, you shouldn't reload it.

Comment: Actually, the problem may be that `Create` has it. When you call `CreateEmployee`, that breaks it for when you call `EditEmployee` later.

Comment: @Barmar I removed the script calls from both of the files and still get the error.  I did notice that I have another error before this one. GET http://localhost:57280/Home/Edit?taskId=8 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 error means a problem in the server script, check your server error log for the reason.

Comment: @Barmar Fixed my 500 error, but still getting the ph.dialog is not a function.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I am using JavaScript 3.3 and just found that .load was removed in version 3.0 could that be my problem and if so, how do I fix it?